# WPF XAML binding properties within a ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to create a `ControlTemplate` representing a `Slider` and a `TextBox` (and a `Label`), where the text of the `TextBox` should show the value of the `Slider`.

I can't figure out how to correctly setup the binding between the `Slider`'s `Value` property and the `TextBox`' `Text` property.

This is my `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myslider" TargetType="Slider">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Label>Slider</Label>
        <Slider 
            Width="100" 
            Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
        <TextBox Width="40" 
            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                Path=Value}">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>              
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here I instantiate 3 Slider using the ControlTemplate:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider Template="{StaticResource myslider}"></Slider>
    <Slider Template="{StaticResource myslider}"></Slider>
    <Slider Template="{StaticResource myslider}"></Slider>
</StackPanel>
```

This ends up looking like this:

[image]

The goal is that each slider controls the value within the indivual TextBoxes.

Comment: There should not be a Slider in the Template of a Slider. That would be two Sliders. You should at least bind the two Sliders' Values by another RelativeSource TemplatedParent Binding.

Comment: Are there only 3?  If you have more then this should be an itemscontrol and each slider textbox pair an item.

Comment: As it is, maybe this should be a usercontrol you use 3 times. Each usercontrol has it's own namescope so you could bind on elementname

Comment: @Andy there are not only 3. There will be many.

Comment: @Clemens Are you able to produce an example of that?

Comment: Sure I am, but that would not make much sense here. Consider moving the StackPanel with the Label, Slider and TextBox into the ItemTempate of an ItemsControl. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Depending on how these are arranged in your view, you might want a wrappanel or uniformgrid as the itemspanel of this itemscontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using a User Control as a first choice. But if we follow your line of thought the shared value of the Slider and the TextBox should be the Value dependency property on the parent Slider.

The tested code is as following :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="myslider" TargetType="Slider">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label>Slider</Label>

            <Slider 
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Delay=10}"
                    
                Minimum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Minimum,Mode=OneWay}"
                    
                Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Maximum,Mode=OneWay}"
                    
                Width="100" 
                />

            <TextBox Width="100" 
                Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Delay=10}">
            </TextBox>
                
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <Slider Template="{StaticResource myslider}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></Slider>
        <Slider Template="{StaticResource myslider}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></Slider>
        <Slider Template="{StaticResource myslider}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></Slider>
    </StackPanel>
        
</Grid>
```